# Descargar xml desde FTP

Tags: java, android

Estoy probando con el siguiente código para descargar varios xml desde un ftp. El primer xml lo descarga correctamente pero a partir del segundo devuelve `null`. ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacer esto?

```
private Vector<InputStream> descargarContenido()  {

    FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
    Vector<InputStream> inputstreams = new Vector<InputStream>();
    try {
        mFTPClient.connect("ftp");

    mFTPClient.login("usuario","password");
    mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/carpeta/xml");
    InputStream input1 = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream("1.xml");
        inputstreams.add(input1);

    InputStream input2 = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream("2.xml");
        inputstreams.add(input2);

    InputStream input3 = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream("3.xml");
        inputstreams.add(input3);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error al descargar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return inputstreams;
}
```

**Edición:**

He intentado usar el código propuesto por @Ajeno pero obtengo un error al leer el segundo xml, el primero me carga el flujo pero el segundo obtengo este error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2146) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078) at
>   MainActivity.descargarContenido(MainActivity.java:544)
>   at
>   MainActivity.parsearXmlDeFTP(MainActivity.java:292)
>   at MainActivity.access$1000(MainActivity.java:32)
>   at
>   MainActivity$TareaDescargaXml.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:228)
>   at
>   MainActivity$TareaDescargaXml.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:222)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) E/WindowManager: Activity
>   MainActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{53459c08
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,486} that was originally added here
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity MainActivity
>   has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{53459c08
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,486} that was originally added here at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:354) at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281) at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116) at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:104) at
>   MainActivity.mostrarbarra(MainActivity.java:202)
>   at MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:32)
>   at MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:174)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)E/EGL_genymotion: egl:
>   current context mark for deletion

Comment: Creo que te conviene leer antes el inputstream, lo que veo es que los 3 apuntan al mismo 3.xml, puesto que la referencia de mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream es la misma.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, ¿a que te refieres cuando dices leer antes el inputstream?

Comment: El segundo es un nullPointer estás seguro que existe el archivo 2.xml en el ftp?

Comment: Totalmente seguro que existe el archivo.

Comment: te corregí abajo el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parece el problema radica en que tienes la referencia del InputStream, en ningún momento cierras o das flush al contenido. Como su nombre dice es flujo de entrada, por lo que los 3 archivos viajarían por el mismo canal de comunicación.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
private List<byte[]> descargarContenido() {

    FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
    List<byte[]> inputstreams = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    try {
        mFTPClient.connect("ftp");

        mFTPClient.login("usuario","password");
        mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/carpeta/xml");
        FTPFile[] filesArray = mFTPClient.listFiles();
        if (filesArray != null && filesArray.length > 0) {
            for (FTPFile file : filesArray) {
                if (!file.isFile()) {
                    continue;
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                mFTPClient.retrieveFile(file.getName(), baos);
                inputstreams.add(baos.toByteArray());
                baos.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error al descargar datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return inputstreams;
}
```

Cambié los Vector por List ya que es sincronizado ese método y trae consigo una pérdida en performance y la documentación de java lo recomienda.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

La librería es de Apache la consigues de este lugar.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Me basé en este https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911772/ftp-multiple-files-using-apache-commons-into-a-local-directory para los múltiples archivos.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido voy a probar tu solución.

Comment: De momento he probado con este método y obtengo un error al leer el segundo xml, el primero me carga el flujo pero el segundo obtengo este error. "java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()"

Comment: Puedes agregar el stack trace completo

Comment: @F.Sola no agreges el nuevo error a la respuesta, edita tu pregunta en su lugar. Por esta vez, lo he añadido yo, revisalo. Saludos.

Comment: Ya hice los cambios, puede que el null lo esté arrojando por que estamos cerrando el flujo, prueba con los nuevos cambios que realicé @F.Sola

Comment: @Ajeno he probado los cambios que hicistes, y de momento sigo obteniendo los mismos errores. La idea de esta función es obtener los xml de un servidor ftp para luego parsearlos, para ello utilizo XmlPullparser, llamando a la función descargar datos del ftp y descargando uno por uno funciona sin problemas, pero tarda unos 30 segundos en descargar los xml y parsearlo con 4G a full de cobertura. Los xml son de 1 kb y unas 25 lineas para que te hagas una idea.

Comment: Son 16 xml que no lo he comentado anteriormente.

Comment: @F.Sola actualicé la respuesta